# How to combine multiple property decorators in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I have a class `Template` with a property `_id` which has decorators from `class-transformer` and `typed-graphql`

```
import {classToPlain, Exclude, Expose, plainToClass, Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { ExposeToGraphQL } from '../../decorators/exposeToGraphQL';
import { Field, ID, MiddlewareInterface, NextFn, ObjectType, ResolverData } from 'type-graphql';
import { getClassForDocument, InstanceType, prop, Typegoose } from 'typegoose';
/**
  * Class
  * @extends Typegoose
  */
@Exclude()
@ObjectType()
class Template extends Typegoose {
  // @Expose and @Type should be both covered by ExposeToGraphQL
  // @Expose()
  @Type(() => String)
  @ExposeToGraphQL()
  @Field(() => ID)
  public _id?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
}
```

Now I try to combine those two into a new custom property decorator:

```
/**
 *
 */
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';
import 'reflect-metadata';

const formatMetadataKey: Symbol = Symbol('ExposeToGraphQL');

function ExposeToGraphQL() {
  console.log('ExposeToGraphQL');

  return Expose();
}

function getExposeToGraphQL(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
  console.log('getExposeToGraphQL');

  return Reflect.getMetadata(formatMetadataKey, target, propertyKey);
}

export {
  ExposeToGraphQL,
  getExposeToGraphQL,
};
```

The custom decorator works if I only return the result of `Expose()`, but I don't know how to combine `@Expose` and `@Type` in `@ExposeToGraphQL()`.

Comment: If you want `ExposeToGraphQL` to serve the purpose of both `Expose` and `Type`, doesn't it need to take the same parameter that `Type` does, for starters?

Comment: I thought to worry about parameters later :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
import { Expose, Type, TypeOptions, ExposeOptions } from 'class-transformer';

/**
 * Combines @Expose then @Types decorators.
 * @param exposeOptions options that passes to @Expose()
 * @param typeFunction options that passes to @Type()
 */
function ExposeToGraphQL(exposeOptions?: ExposeOptions, typeFunction?: (type?: TypeOptions) => Function) {
  const exposeFn = Expose(exposeOptions);
  const typeFn = Type(typeFunction);

  return function (target: any, key: string) {
    typeFn(target, key);
    exposeFn(target, key);
  }
}
```

Then you can use that decorator as follow:

```
class Template extends Typegoose {
    @ExposeToGraphQL(/*exposeOptions*/ undefined, /*typeFunction*/ () => String)
    @Field(() => ID)
    public _id?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
}
```

---

You can find official documentation for decorator [in this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).

`@Expose` and `@Type()` are basically [Decorator Factories](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-factories). The main purpose of a decorator factory:

- it return a function
- that function will be called at runtime (right after the class, in this case is `Template`, was defined) with 2 arguments:

  - class prototype (`Template.prototype`)
  - name of the property which the decorator attached to (`_id`).

If two or more decorators are attached to a same property (called as [Decorator Composition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-composition)), they are evaluated as follow:

- The factory functions are executed in the same order as they are written in code
- The functions returned by factory functions are executed in **reversed** order