# Combine several host bindings into one single decorator

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I have components that use host binding decorators to display component selectors so that they take all the available width :

```
@HostBinding('style.width.%')
@HostBinding('style.height.%')
private readonly SIZE = 100;

@HostBinding('style.display')
private readonly DISPLAY = 'block';

@HostBinding('style.box-sizing')
private readonly BOX_MODEL = 'border-box';
```

What I would like to do is create a single decorator (at class or property level, I don't care) that includes all of these ones, so that I don't have to rewrite this everytime.

Right now, I made it work by creating a superclass and letting my other classes extend it, but it has a lot of limitations and inconveniences, hence my question.

Any help, even if it's documentation, is greatly appreciated !

**EDIT** I have also found [this SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969492/how-to-combine-multiple-property-decorators-in-typescript), but the difference with my issue is the variables having a value, and I can't seem to find how would I pass those values to my decorator.

**EDIT 2** To explain my need : I have this component

```
@Component(...)
export class MyAngularComponent extends HostBinderComponent {...}
```

and this one

```
export class HostBinderComponent {
  @HostBinding('style.width.%')
  @HostBinding('style.height.%')
  private readonly SIZE = 100;

  @boxComponent()
  private readonly DISPLAY;

  @HostBinding('style.box-sizing')
  private readonly BOX_MODEL = 'border-box';
}
```

And my end goal would be to delete the superclass and have something like

```
@Component(...)
@BoxComponent()
export class MyAngularComponent {...}
```

So that I don't have to use `extends` or `HostBinding` in my Angular components anymore !

Comment: You want the decorator to be applied just to these exact properties ? with these exact values ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir for the sake of comprehension, yes, I simply want a decorator such as (for instance) `@BoxComponent` that will apply all of these 4 decorators to a class (with the given values)

Comment: @trichetriche (remove the extends in the last code block)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply a decorator involves calling the `__decorate` helper function. This function can be either generated by the compiler or used from a custom tslib. Angular uses teh `tslib` module for the `__decorate` function, and we can use the `__decorate` from there. (We could copy the version ts generates or write our own simpler version of `__decorate` that calls the decorator function, but it's best to just use the same way of invoking the decorators as the framework would use)

Armed with this function (and after inspecting how TS invokes the decorator for the fields) we can easily create our own compound decorator:

```
import { __decorate } from 'tslib';


function BoxHostBindings() {
  return function(target) {
    __decorate([
      HostBinding('style.width.%'),
      HostBinding('style.height.%'),
    ], target.prototype, "SIZE", void 0);
    __decorate([
      HostBinding('style.display'),
    ], target.prototype, "DISPLAY", void 0);
    __decorate([
      HostBinding('style.box-sizing'),
    ], target.prototype, "BOX_MODEL", void 0);
  }
}
```

**Note**: I have not tested this extensively, but is seems to work, and I would expect it to work.

Usage:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
@BoxHostBindings()
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'testapp';

  private readonly SIZE = 100;
  private readonly DISPLAY = 'block'
  private readonly BOX_MODEL = 'border-box';
}
```

**Edit**

Setting values for the properties is a bit more difficult. We don't have easy access to the constructor execution so we can't do it then.

One option is to define the values on `prototype`, since the values are read-only this should work fine:

```
function BoxHostBindings(size: number, display: string, box_model: string) {
  return function(target) {
    target.prototype.SIZE = size;
    target.prototype.DISPLAY = display;
    target.prototype.BOX_MODEL = box_model;
    __decorate([
      HostBinding('style.width.%'),
      HostBinding('style.height.%'),
    ], target.prototype, "SIZE", void 0);
    __decorate([
      HostBinding('style.display'),
    ], target.prototype, "DISPLAY", void 0);
    __decorate([
      HostBinding('style.box-sizing'),
    ], target.prototype, "BOX_MODEL", void 0);
  }
}
```

We could also define properties in order to allow the user to modify the value, and store it in a field ('_' + name), but return the default if the value is undefined:

```
function BoxHostBindings(size: number, display: string, box_model: string) {
  return function(target) {
    function propHelper(name: string, defaultValue: any) {
      Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, name, {
        get: function () {
            return this['_' + name] || defaultValue;
        },
        set: function(value: any ) {
          this['_' + name] = value
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
      });
    }
    propHelper("SIZE", size);
    propHelper("DISPLAY", display);
    propHelper("BOX_MODEL", box_model);
    __decorate([
      HostBinding('style.width.%'),
      HostBinding('style.height.%'),
    ], target.prototype, "SIZE", void 0);
    __decorate([
      HostBinding('style.display'),
    ], target.prototype, "DISPLAY", void 0);
    __decorate([
      HostBinding('style.box-sizing'),
    ], target.prototype, "BOX_MODEL", void 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: In your solution, you're not giving any value (`100, 'block', 'border-box'`) to the function, is that normal ?

Comment: That value would still be defined in your class .. This just combines the decorators.. not the field declarations .. You would still need to define the fields (otherwise they will be null). You could assign default values for them to the prototype ... that could also work

Comment: So I still would need to write 4 times this `BoxHostBindings` ?

Comment: @trichetriche no, it's meant to be applied to the class.. but you would need to declare the fields. I'll add a usage sample.

Comment: No need, I got it :) But it's not what I expected, I am going to edit my question to show some use-case myself and explain my issue better. Anyway, thank you for that piece of information, I'll try to work around that !

Comment: I have updated my question if you wish to take a look at it !

Comment: @trichetriche added versions for defining the values too

Comment: Sorry, I just logged in SOF (disconnected yesterday when I went home), but I tried something myself and found a clean way of doing this. Again, thank you for answer, that (kind of) explained me what the decorators were doing, allowing me to find a way to resolve my issue. I have posted an answer to my own post to show what I did, but I'll mark your answer as accepted because I wouldn't have done it without :)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials, I have managed to find a very lean and understandable way of doing what I wanted to achieve.

After eading [@TitanCernicovaDragomir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745433/4676340) and the [source code of the decorators](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.1.3/packages/core/src/util/decorators.ts#L146), I managed to understand that :

- A host binding decorator needs a value (as opposed to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969492/how-to-combine-multiple-property-decorators-in-typescript))
- The decorator relies on the variable name (= `key`, provided by the decorator)
- It finds the key in the `target` (also provided by the decorator)
- The decorator returns a function that simply needs that target & key

Which, in the end, gives this very simple code :

```
export const boxComponent: ClassDecorator = (component) => {
  const bindings = [
    { id: 'HOST_BINDINGS_WIDTH', ngStyle: 'style.width.%', value: 100},
    { id: 'HOST_BINDINGS_HEIGHT', ngStyle: 'style.height.%', value: 100},
    { id: 'HOST_BINDINGS_DISPLAY', ngStyle: 'style.display', value: 'block'},
    { id: 'HOST_BINDINGS_BOX_MODEL', ngStyle: 'style.box-sizing', value: 'border-box'},
  ];

  bindings.forEach(binding => {
    component.prototype[binding.id] = binding.value;

    const hostBindingFn = HostBinding(binding.ngStyle);
    hostBindingFn(component.prototype, binding.id);
  });
};
```

As a sidenote, I have bound my variables to my component's prototype (which is the `target` BTW) so that variables don't interfere with my existing component, but it should work without touching the prototype !