# plainToClass does not convert a Date to string

Tags: typescript, class-transformer

According to [the docs](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#%D1%81onverting-date-strings-into-date-objects) a `Date` object should be converted to a `string`:

> Note, that dates will be converted to strings when you'll try to convert class object to plain object.

My example-code with class-transformer `0.2.3` does not work as expected:

```
class TestDate {
  @Type(() => Date)
  aDate!: Date;
}

  const testDate = new TestDate();
  testDate.aDate = new Date();
  const result: any = classToPlain(testDate);
  console.log(typeof result.aDate);
```

This prints `object` to the console, but I'd expect `string`.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following sentence in the documentation is wrong (see [class-transformer#326](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/326)):

> Note, that dates will be converted to strings when you'll try to convert class object to plain object.

The solution is to use `@Transform`:

```js
  @Transform(value => (value as Date).toISOString(), {
    toPlainOnly: true
  })
```

[Codesandbox example with workaround](https://codesandbox.io/s/class-transformer326-nbjk7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Note that in more recent versions, the argument to Transform function is now an object that has a `value` prop rather than just the value, so it needs to be extracted. E.g. with destructuring `@Transform(({ value }) => ...`

Answer (score 6):

To expand on TmTron's answer, I needed to create two transformers - one in each direction. I then combined them into one decorator using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969492/how-to-combine-multiple-property-decorators-in-typescript):

```
// TransformDate.ts
import { Transform } from "class-transformer";

export default function TransformDate() {
  const toPlain = Transform((value) => (value as Date).toISOString(), {
    toPlainOnly: true,
  });

  const toClass = Transform((value) => new Date(value), {
    toClassOnly: true,
  });

  return function (target: any, key: string) {
    toPlain(target, key);
    toClass(target, key);
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
// User.ts
import TransformDate from './TransformDate';

export default class User {
  id: string;
  @TransformDate()
  createdDate: Date;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Note that in more recent versions, the argument to Transform function is now an object that has a `value` prop rather than just the value, so it needs to be extracted. E.g. with destructuring `@Transform(({ value }) => ...`